# How to calculate invoice total amounts of multiple inputs using jquery?

Tags: jquery, invoice

I retrieve all items from `order_items` table using a `foreach` loop and then I want to modify quantity and prices of each item.

What I want is to calculate instantly the `subtotal` and `total` amount of all items using jQuery but I couldn't find a way to make it work.

```js
$(".price").on('change', function() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var total_ht = $("#total_ht").val();
  var price = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var quantity = $("#quantity-" + id).val();

  subtotal = price * quantity;
  total = subtotal + (subtotal * 20 / 100)
  // Single row subtotal
  $("#subtotal-" + id).val(subtotal);
  // Single row total
  $("#total-" + id).val(total);
  // All  rows subtotal
  total_ht = parseFloat(total_ht + subtotal);
  $("#total_ht").val(total_ht);
})


$(".quantity").on('change', function() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var total_ht = $("#total_ht").val();
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var price = $("#price-" + id).val();

  subtotal = price * quantity;
  total = subtotal + (subtotal * 20 / 100);
  // Single row subtotal   
  $("#subtotal-" + id).val(subtotal);
  // Single row total
  $("#total-" + id).val(total);
  // All  rows subtotal
  $("#total_ht").val(total_ht);
})
```

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <?php foreach($orderItems as $item): ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="<?= $item->quantity ?>" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>" id="quantity-<?= $item->id ?>">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" name="price[]" class="form-control price" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>" value="<?= $item->unity_price ?>" id="price-<?= $item->id ?>">
            </td>

            <td>
              <input type="number" name="subtotal[]" class="subtotal" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>" value="<?= $item->total_ht_price ?>" id="subtotal-<?= $item->id ?>" readonly>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input type="number" name="total[]" class="total" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>" value="<?= $item->total_ttc_price ?>" id="total-<?= $item->id ?>" readonly>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table table-white">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Total HT
            </th>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input type="number" name="total_ht" id="total_ht" class="form-control total_ht" readonly value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">TVA
            </th>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input type="number" name="totalTVA" id="totalTVA" class="form-control totalTVA" readonly value="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Total TTC
            </th>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input type="number" name="totalTTC" id="totalTTC" class="totalTTC" readonly value="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: What is not working is displaying the TOTAL amount of all inputs with the class(TOTAL) in an input called TOTAL with id(TOTAL_AMOUNT)

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all details. What did you try to check **why** this is not working? It should not be to hard to either use breakpoints for the calculation, or log the steps using `console.log`

Comment: I added a screenshot to illustrate more the issue

Comment: The problem is that you don't fully *recalculate* the total each time, instead using a "running" total.  And in the 2nd (quantity event), you don't change `total_ht` at all.

Comment: `$("#total_ht").val($(".subtotal").map((i, e)=>$(e).val() * 1).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a delegated version

I use input event since it triggers on paste too

```js
$("table tbody tr input").on('input', function() {
  let total = 0;
  $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
    const price = +$(this).find(".price").val()
    const qty = +$(this).find(".quantity").val()
    const val = price*qty
    total += val;
    $(this).find(".subtotal").val(val)
    $(this).find(".total").val(total)
    
  })
  $("#total_ht").val(total)
}).trigger("input")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="2" data-id="id1" id="quantity-1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="price[]" class="form-control price" data-id="id2" value="3" id="price-1">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="number" name="subtotal[]" class="subtotal" data-id="id3" value="" id="subtotal-1" readonly>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="number" name="total[]" class="total" data-id="id4" value="" id="total-1" readonly>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="2" data-id="id5" id="quantity-2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="price[]" class="form-control price" data-id="id6>" value="3" id="price-2">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="number" name="subtotal[]" class="subtotal" data-id="id7" value="" id="subtotal-2" readonly>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="number" name="total[]" class="total" data-id="id9" value="" id="total-2" readonly>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="number" id="total_ht" readonly />
```